# Create new Strings from other String (Java)

Tags: java, string, parsing

I want to extract data from a given String.
Example:

I have something like:

```
String s = "tree;dog;house;computer sience";
```

And I want as result:

```
String a = "tree";
String b = "dog";
String c = "house";
String d = "computer sience";
```

The substrings have variable length, but are seperated with ";". Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Do you always have 4 variables in 's'?

Comment: Yes, always 4 variables

Comment: @Lukas W. Have a look and Approve the answer if it serves your purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way:

```
        String inpu="tree;dog;house;computer sience";
        String[] sArray =  s.split(";");
        for (String ss: inputString) {
            System.out.print(ss+"\n");
        }
```

Output:

```
tree
dog
house
computer sience
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s="tree;dog;house;computer sience";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s).useDelimiter(";");
String a = scanner.next();
String b = scanner.next();
String c = scanner.next();
String d = scanner.next();
scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s="tree;dog;house;computer sience";

    String[] strings = s.split(";");
    String a = strings[0];
    String b = strings[1];
    String c = strings[2];
    String d = strings[3];

//test with:
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(d);
```